# Splitting a file into multiple files and placing them into a separate folder

Tags: shell, awk

I have a csv file and I am trying to split that file based on a column value and creating new files. But I would like to place them in a specified directory. This is the code I am using. Any inputs how I can place the files into another directory

```
 AWK -F '{print $2 > "$2.csv"}' inputfile.csv
```

Comment: Please include some sample input, and the results you see when you run your command on that sample input. Then tell us how your results differ from what you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

To your question "How to place the file in another directory", there are many answers, but the simplest could be just to specify the target directory:
`AWK -F , '{print $2 > "targetDirectory/a.csv"}' ./inputfile.csv`